# Reorder LayoutControlGroups inside another LayoutControlGroup on runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I've got `LayoutControlGroup` with few other `LayoutControlGroup`s inside.

What I need to do is to reorder them into specific order on runtime.

For example, when form shows up I've got those groups in such order:

```
[Group0]
[Group1]
[Group2]
[Group3]
[Group4]
```

And then I get some data from DB and need to reorder groups according to that data, for example just reverse the order:

```
[Group4]
[Group3]
[Group2]
[Group1]
[Group0]
```

What I tried already:

```
List<BaseLayoutItem> currentOrder = lcgParentGroup.Items.Cast<object>().Where(c => c is BaseLayoutItem).Cast<BaseLayoutItem>().Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("lcgInnerGroup") && char.IsDigit(c.Name.Last())).ToList();
currentOrder.Sort((x, y) => System.Collections.Comparer.Default.Compare(x.Location.Y, y.Location.Y));

// Example order
List<BaseLayoutItem> requiredOrder = new List<BaseLayoutItem>(currentOrder);
requiredOrder.Reverse();

for (int i = 1; i < requiredOrder.Count; ++i)
{
    // I just move every group after every relative group.
    BaseLayoutItem relative = lcgParentGroup.Items.FindByName(requiredOrder[i - 1].Name);

    DevExpress.XtraLayout.Customization.LayoutItemDragController dragController = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.Customization.LayoutItemDragController(requiredOrder[i], relative, MoveType.Outside, InsertLocation.After, LayoutType.Vertical);
    bool result = requiredOrder[i].Move(dragController);    
}
```

However everytime the `result` is `false`.

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. The groups have to be Visibile (Visibility.Always) to move them. Dunno why.

The solution pseudo-code:

```
try
{
    groups.BeginUpdate();

    List<object> dataFromDB = ...;

    // Znamy aktualną kolejność grup
    List<BaseLayoutItem> currentOrder = groups.Items.Cast<object>().Where(c => c is BaseLayoutItem).Cast<BaseLayoutItem>().ToList();

    // Sort as visibile in form
    currentOrder.Sort((x, y) => System.Collections.Comparer.Default.Compare(x.Location.Y, y.Location.Y));

    // Save old visibilities
    LayoutVisibility[] allVisibilities = currentOrder.Select(x => x.Visibility).ToArray();
    currentOrder.ForEach(x => x.Visibility = LayoutVisibility.Always);

    List<BaseLayoutItem> requiredOrder = ...; // prepare required order

    // Make requiredOrder[0] topmost group

    // Move
    for (int i = 1; i < requiredOrder.Count; ++i)
    {
        BaseLayoutItem relative = groups.Items.FindByName(requiredOrder[i - 1].Name);
        BaseLayoutItem toMove = groups.Items.FindByName(requiredOrder[i].Name);

        toMove.Move(relative, InsertType.Bottom);
    }

    // Restore visibilities
    for (int i = 0; i < currentOrder.Count; ++i)
    {
        currentOrder[i].Visibility = allVisibilities[i];
    }

}
finally
{
    groups.EndUpdate();
}
```